# Count number of pages of a PDF file in a LAMP server

Tags: unix, pdf, lamp, ghostscript

How can I count number of pages of a PDF file in a LAMP server before splitting it?

I'm trying to do this with Ghost Script but i don't find documentation about it.

PHP doesn't seem to be the right way and I don't know any other Unix Software which can do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can answer your own question :)

Comment: You could also say: `pdfinfo pdfname | awk '/^Pages:/ {print $2}'`

Comment: Your solution should go in an answer and be removed from the question.  Or devnull should create an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solution

```
pdfinfo [pdfname] | grep Pages | awk '{total=$2}END{printf total}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following without any additional linux packages:

```
foundPages=$(strings < $PDF_FILE | sed -n 's|.*Count -\{0,1\}\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*|\1|p' | sort -rn | head -n 1)
```